# Query with Parameter not always supplied

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm creating a user authentication & registration API, and in the `register` endpoint I'm checking to see if a user with the supplied username or email address already exists. The tricky thing is that the username is not required, so it is sometimes undefined. If there are any existing users with an `undefined` username, and someone tries to register without supplying one (aka with `undefined` as the username), it finds the previous `undefined` user and won't let the registration continue.

How do I query:

> Find one user with the email address [email address] OR with the username [username] if the username is not `undefined`

Here's my route (using express):

```
exports.register = (req, res, next) => {    
    const email = req.body.email.toLowerCase();
    const username = (req.body.username) ? req.body.username.toLowerCase() : undefined;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const name = req.body.name;

    // Return error if no email provided
    if (!email) {
        return res.status(422).send({ error: 'You must enter an email address.' });
    }

    if (!password) {
        return res.status(422).send({ error: 'You must enter a password.' });
    }

    const queryUser = User.findOne({ $or: [{ email }, { username }] }).exec();

    queryUser.then((existingUser) => {
        if (existingUser) {
            const field = (existingUser.email === req.body.email) ? 'email address' : 'username';
            return res.status(422).send({ error: `A user with that ${field} already exists.` });
        }

        const user = new User({
            email, password, username, name,
        });

        user.save().then((newUser) => {
            const userInfo = setUserInfo(newUser);
            res.status(201).json({
                token: `JWT${generateToken(userInfo)}`,
                user: userInfo,
            });
        }).catch(userErr => next(userErr));
    }).catch(err => next(err));

    return true;
};
```

I suppose I could just make a different query if a username is not defined, like so:

```
let queryUser;
if (username) {
    queryUser = User.findOne({ $or: [{ email }, { username: { $ne: undefined, username } }] }).exec();
} else {
    queryUser = User.findOne({ email }).exec();
}
```

But I'd rather learn more about how to handle this kind of thing with Mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or instead you can just conditionally build the query:

```
var query = { $or: [ { email } ] };

if ( req.body.hasOwnProperty('username') ) {
  query.$or.push({ "username": { "$ne": req.body.username.toLowerCase() } }
}

queryUser = User.findOne(query).exec();
```

These are just JavaScript objects and can be manipulated like any other.

This is why MongoDB query language is based on standard data structure formats

Comment: My question was about how to do this in the query itself - without having to modify it. But, after digging more into the Mongo docs, when `undefined` is passed in as a value, it matches everything. (The same reason why `collection.find({})` returns all documents.)